# Trailing constraint

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, xcode-storyboard

I'm currently learning about auto layout and trying to setup some table cells to show the same across devices

The layout shows correctly across iPhone devices, but on iPads its stretched.

I believe I've narrowed it down to the trailing constraint, when I remove it it displays correctly on both device types but Xcode throws a missing constraint warning.

The constraints are using less than or equal, which works fine on iPhone but doesn't display correctly on iPad. iPad works if I use more than or equal, but this messes iPhone up

These are the constraints
[image]

This is how it should appear on both devices.
[image]

But this is how it appears on iPads
[image]

Comment: So what are your constraints?

Comment: added them above

Comment: You probably want to give Width constraints to your Text Fields, and remove the `Trailing = Partial Bag.trailing + 87.5` constraint.

Comment: But how I then stop Xcodes warning about trailing constraints missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting a wide text field on iPad is because you're constraining the "Partial Bag" text field to the trailing edge of the cell.

Without looking at your actual Storyboard, not sure why you're getting constraint conflicts.

This is how I set up your cell, and have no issues (other than the known bug with text vertical alignment in IB when laying out rounded-border text fields):

[image]

Note that I gave `Full Bag` a Width of `32`, and constrained the width of `Partial Bag` to be equal to `Full Bag`. No constraints to the Trailing edge of the cell's content view.

The result, in Portrait and Landscape orientations (which will, of course, layout similarly on an iPad):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should set up a width constraint on both `UITextField`s. That way, the first (and second) one won't stretch. Another option would be to make the trailing constraint of the second `UITextField` be equal or greater.

Comment: I had tried with the greater than but it causes overlapping on the iPhone. I tried setting widths of the text fields but they were ignored

Comment: @CeriTurner But what if you leave everything on "less + equal" and then only change the trailing of the second `UITextField` to "greater + equal"?